# How to check a boolean condition in EL?

Tags: java, jsp, el

Is this correct?

```
<c:if test="${theBooleanVariable == false}">It's false!</c:if>
```

Or could I do this?

```
<c:if test="${!theBooleanVariable}">It's false!</c:if>
```

Answer (score 131, accepted):

You can have a look at the EL (expression language) description [here](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html).

Both your code are correct, but I prefer the second one, as comparing a boolean to `true` or `false` is redundant.

For better readibility, you can also use the `not` operator:

```
<c:if test="${not theBooleanVariable}">It's false!</c:if>
```

Answer (score 22):

Both works. Instead of `==` you can write `eq`

Answer (score 6):

You can check this way too

```
<c:if test="${theBooleanVariable ne true}">It's false!</c:if>
```