# Conditionally include JSF viewParam

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jstl

I'm trying to include `<f:viewParam>` and `<f:viewAction>` tags conditionally in my JSF pages with JSTLs `<c:if>` as *I don't want to manually specify the viewParams in every single JSF page*. Unfortunately it is not working...

**metadata_include.xhtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core">
    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="from" value="#{loginBean.from}" />
        <c:if test="#{detailsId eq 'true'}">
            <f:viewParam id="detailsid" name="detailsid" value="#{detailsBean.detailsId}" />
            <f:viewAction action="#{detailsBean.onload}" />
        </c:if>
    </f:metadata>
</ui:composition>
```

**details.xhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
<h:head>
    <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/metadata_include.xhtml">
        <ui:param name="detailsId" value="true" />
    </ui:include>
</h:head>
<h:body>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Anybody knows what I'm doing wrong or knows a different way how to achieve this kind of behavior?

I also tried it with `<h:panelGroup rendered="#{detailsId eq 'true'}">` without success.

Comment: hy, why you put metadata_include.xhtml in WEB-INF folder?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915716/how-to-check-a-boolean-condition-in-el

Comment: @BalusC care to explain why the question is a duplicate? So far I don't use templates and I don't see how I could conditionally specify viewParams with it.

Comment: But I'm neither using the template attribute nor a `<ui:insert>` tag? How would I include the conditional viewParams?

Comment: Really? So either I define static viewParams (same on every page) or I need to specify the viewParams in every single JSF page?! What a major letdown... Still don't see why the question is a duplicate though as the linked answer does not provide a solution where you can keep the viewParams dynamic!